How can I carry all kibana configurations such as roles, users, index patterns to another kibana which runs in another server
I have a kibana server running in a server for a while now.
I installed and setup kibana to another server and I need to have same configurations with the older ones. And it is taking so much time just to redo it from UI. Is there any tool to export and import all configurations to new one?
I am talking about: user definitions, role definitions, role_bindings, index patterns, space definitions, ILP definitions exc.
I can do it from UI, but it takes so much time I don't want to get into it. If there is no alternative way, I had to do it like that.
